# Multi Tabs bootstrap with vimeo chapter

Tags: jquery, list, video, tabs, vimeo

I'm trying to integrate four video of vimeo in multi chapter by tabs. (One multichapter's video by tab) 
But when I move on next tab the video continues to play...

I would like if it was possible that when I click on next tab that stop video of previous tab + when I click on item chapter list (on this new tab) the video play.

My code :

```html
 <section id="be" class="pad-xl">
      <div class="container"><!--tab contaire--> 
      
      
<ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" role="tablist">
  <li  class="active"><a href="#plani" data-toggle="tab">La Planification</a></li>
  <li ><a href="#quali" data-toggle="tab">La qualité</a></li>
  <li ><a href="#prod" data-toggle="tab">La production</a></li>
  <li ><a href="#config" data-toggle="tab">Le configurateur</a></li>
</ul>
       
       <div class="tab-content"><!--tab content--> 
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
       <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="plani"><!--tab panel--> 

      
        
        <div class="row"><!--2 Blocs--> 
        
 
 <div class="col-xs-4 feature wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay="0.3s"><!--FEATURES --> 
        
        <div class="list-group">
 
    <a href="#" data-seek="53.6" class="timecode list-group-item active">Introduction<span class="badge">14</span></a>
  
    <a href="#" data-seek="53.6" class="timecode list-group-item list-group-item-action">Blabla</a>
    <a href="#" data-seek="53.6" class="timecode list-group-item list-group-item-action">Blabla2</a>
    <a href="#" data-seek="53.6" class="timecode list-group-item list-group-item-action">Blabla3</a>  
    <a href="#" data-seek="53.6" class="timecode list-group-item list-group-item-action">Blabla4</a> 
    <a href="#" data-seek="53.6" class="timecode list-group-item list-group-item-action">5</a> 
  </div>
 </div>
   
 <div class="col-xs-8 feature wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay="0.3s"><!--FEATURES --> 
        
 <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
   <iframe id="thevideo" class="embed-responsive-item" src="//player.vimeo.com/video/181964440?api=1" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
  
 </div
 </div></div>
        
 </div><!--2 Blocs--> 
        
        
        
        </div><!--tab panel--> 
        
         
         
         <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="quali"><!--tab panel--> 

      
        
        <div class="row"><!--2 Blocs--> 
        
 
 <div class="col-xs-4 feature wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay="0.3s"><!--FEATURES --> 
        
        <div class="list-group">
 
    <a href="#" data-seek="53.6" class="timecode list-group-item active">Introduction<span class="badge">14</span></a>
  
    <a href="#" data-seek="53.6" class="timecode list-group-item list-group-item-action">PIC & Plan d’approvisionnement</a>
    <a href="#" data-seek="53.6" class="timecode list-group-item list-group-item-action">PDP</a>
    <a href="#" data-seek="53.6" class="timecode list-group-item list-group-item-action">Plan de charges</a>  
    <a href="#" data-seek="53.6" class="timecode list-group-item list-group-item-action">L’ordonnancement</a> 
    <a href="#" data-seek="53.6" class="timecode list-group-item list-group-item-action">Autres fonctionnalités Planification</a> 
  </div>
 </div>
   
 <div class="col-xs-8 feature wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay="0.3s"><!--FEATURES --> 
        
 <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
   <iframe id="thevideo" class="embed-responsive-item" src="//player.vimeo.com/video/181964440?api=1" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
  
 </div>
 </div>
        
 </div><!--2 Blocs--> 
</div><!--tab panel--> 

   

</div>
<script>
jQuery(function ($) {
    var iframe = document.getElementById('thevideo');
    var player = $f(iframe);
    $('.timecode').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var seekVal = $(this).attr('data-seek');
        player.api('seekTo', seekVal);
    });
});
//@ sourceURL=pen.js
</script>
</section>
```

`enter code here`

Any solutions for this ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve this effect you need to combine the `events` that bootstrap tabs fire and managing `pause` and `play` effects on your Vimeo videos.

**1)** Bootstrap tabs events

Bootstrap tabs events fire a couple of events, from their docs:

> When showing a new tab, the events fire in the following order:
>
> - hide.bs.tab (on the current active tab)
> - show.bs.tab (on the to-be-shown tab)
> - hidden.bs.tab (on the previous active tab, the same one as for the hide.bs.tab event)
> - shown.bs.tab (on the newly-active just-shown tab, the same one as for the show.bs.tab event)

So in order to capture these events you'll need a simple jQuery as such:

JS:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    // You have access to both tabs
  var previousActiveTabId = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('href');
  var newlyActivatedTabId = $(e.target).attr('href');

  // More stuff below
}
```

**2)** Now you have the tab that is going to be active and the previous one, to stop/play the videos I would advise you to use [Vimeos's JavaScript SDK](https://github.com/vimeo/player.js) which contain several utilities. But for out sake you'd be able to such things:

Augmented previous JS:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    // You have access to both tabs
  var previousActiveTabId = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('href');
  var newlyActivatedTabId = $(e.target).attr('href');

    // Now you can stop the video like this
    var playerToPause = new Vimeo.Player($(previousActiveTabId).find('iframe')[0]);
  playerToPause.pause();

  var playerToPlay = new Vimeo.Player($(newlyActivatedTabId).find('iframe')[0]);
  playerToPlay.play();

});
```

And that should do the trick, I've tested this using [This Fiddle, check it out and see if it helps you](https://jsfiddle.net/lucaslazaro/27a476xb/3/).

Comment: @JulienMichaud Did my alternative worked for you? Are you still experiencing problems?

Comment: Hello, don't work for me... :( You can see my response in top.